# Unknown Host Exception while authentciating to JIRA server

Tags: java, jersey, jira, jersey-client

I have been trying to authentciate to JIRA server and have checked number of ways on the internet to do so. But i always get the exception. I am completely new to REST and jersey.

Please help  as where i am getting wrong.

Below is the code snippet:

```
package jiratest;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;

public class JIRA1 {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("admin", "admin"));
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://project.atlassian.net/");
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }
}
```

I am always getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: project.atlassian.net
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:81)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:642)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:459)
    at jiratest.JIRA1.main(JIRA1.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: project.atlassian.net
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:239)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:146)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Well ... the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) says: "Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined."

Comment: UnknownHostException means it can not find the host you specified. Check if it's accesible from where you are running the program. Make sure you are using the right port/protocol if it needs HTTP/HTTPS.